# Object of class Generator could not be converted to string

Tags: php, generator, yield

I have some code that can return massive amount of data. So instead of saving this into an array I wanted to use generators. However, I'm having quite a few problems with it.

Now, when I'm doing it simple like this

```
foreach ($this->test(0,10) as $test) {
    print $test;
}

public function test($from, $to) {
    for ($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting the following output

> 0123456789

Now, I wanted to to the same with a real life example. Like this

```
$posts = $this->getPosts();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    print $post;
}

protected function getPosts()
{
    // Getting the content of the sitemap
    $response = Curl::get('http://wpde.org/sitemap.xml')[0];
    // Loading the string as XML
    $sitemapJson   = simplexml_load_string($response->getContent());
    // This case is true when the sitemap has a link to more sitemaps instead of linking directly to the posts
    if (isset($sitemapJson->sitemap)) {
        foreach ($sitemapJson->sitemap as $post) {
            if (substr($post->loc, -3) === "xml") {
                $this->setUrl((string)$post->loc);
                yield $this->getPosts(); // I also tried it here without the yield, but then I just get an empty output :/
            }
        }
    } 
    // This case is true, when the sitemap has now the direct links to the post
    elseif (isset($sitemapJson->url)) {
        foreach ($sitemapJson->url as $url) {
            yield (string)$url->loc;
        }
    }
}
```

But here I'm getting the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Generator could not be converted to string

The strange thing is, when I'm printing out the URL

```
print $this->url . '<br>';
```

I'm only getting the first URL of the Sitemap. However, if I remove the `yield` parts I'm getting all links of the Sitemap. It just seems like it's somehow stopping there?

Anyway, I'm just not able to print out the data. How would I do this? Thanks!

And without the yield in the first if case there is simply no content.

Comment: You've turned getPosts() into a __recursive__ generator, and each recursive call reloads `$response = Curl::get('http://wpde.org/sitemap.xml')[0];
`. is that really what you planned to do?

Comment: Already thought that this could be a problem. Maybe you can help me. I'm reading in a sitemap. A sitemap can either have direct links to the posts of the blog or sublinks to other sitemaps that have then the links in the posts. So if the sitemap has sublinks to other sitemaps I firstly have to go to these sitemaps and parse the posts. So yes, I wanted to do it recursive (which would've worked without generators) but apperently it doesn't. What would I need to to do fix this? If I put the parsing into another method I would have the problem again of using arrays, right?

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you think of pamelus' approach?

Comment: I would have expected you'd need to pass the xmlfile/url as an argument to the getPosts() call, not simply define the same url/file inside the generator itself

Comment: But `yield $this->getPosts();` will return yield a new instance of a generator to the calling code, not data from that generator; so pamelus's approach eliminates that problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Glad it was such a simple project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
yield $this->getPosts();
```

to

```
foreach($this->getPosts() as $post)
    yield $post;
```

as only one item, not whole "collection" may be yielled at once.

Comment: Wow, haha, that should've been so easy. :p. Ty!